# Handle third party library class depedency which do not have interface

Tags: c#, design, dependency-injection

I am working on [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204119(v=exchg.150).aspx).  A class is made to query mail box and read emails.

```
public class MailReader
{

    private readonly ExchangeService _service;
    private readonly PropertySet _propertySet;

    private readonly IFolderSearch _folder;
    private readonly IMailAttachmentAdapter _attachment;
    private const int MaxEmail = 1000; 

    public MailReader(
        ExchangeService service,
        PropertySet propertySet,
        IFolderSearch folder,
        IMailAttachmentAdapter attachment)
    {
        _service = service;
        _folder = folder;
        _propertySet = propertySet;
        _attachment = attachment;
    }
```

what is the best way to inject `ExchangeService` , `PropertySet` classes are sealed and with no interface. Planning to use [AutoFac](https://autofac.org/) for dependency management.

any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: If you don't need to substitute these dependencies, then injecting the concrete classes like you do seem fine.

Comment: I would hit the vendor with a club, a big one. Who does distribute concrete classes with no interface in 2018?
The 80s have called...

Comment: Create the interface yourself, has the added benefit of decoupling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the simplest, but long-winded, ways to solve this is to use the delegation pattern:

```
interface IDelegatedExchangeService
{
    bool AcceptGzipEncoding { get; set; }
    string ClientRequestId { get; set; }
    ...
}

class ConcreteExchangeService : IDelegatedExchangeService
{
    private ExchangeService _exchangeService;

    public bool AcceptGzipEncoding
    {
        get => _exchangeService.AcceptGzipEncoding;
        set => _exchangeService.AcceptGzipEncoding = value;
    }

    ...
}
```

and to then use `IDelegatedExchangeService` throughout your code.